# What if there's '\0' character in command line input?

Tags: c, command-line-interface

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]);
```

If there's a `'\0'` character in `A`, will it be split into **2** arguments ?

```
./programe "A"
```

I can't reproduce it easily as I can't put an `'\0'` into **A**,but there might be someone who can.

Comment: You can't? `./programe $'A\0B'`

Comment: Is this a concern for security reasons?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ,how does `$'A\0B' ` work here?

Comment: bash interprets escape sequences within `$'...'`.

Comment: It doesn't - or it does and it doesn't.  I have a program, `al`, which prints its arguments one per line (instead of space-separated on a single line like `echo`).  In Bash, `al $'a\0b'` generates just `a` as output.  You'll have to look in the Bash manual for the exact meaning of `$'...'`, same as I will.  I found that `al "a\0b"` produced `a\0b` as output, to my not very big surprise.  So, even though the `$'a\0b' notation includes a null in the string, the `execve()` system call stops copying the argument at the first null, so the hard work achieved nothing useful.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler,seems not the case,`argc` is `3` in this case: `./argc $'A\0B' 2n`

Comment: I realized that my original `al` is not convincing (to me); it would stop at the null in the argument.  So, I wrote this instead: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) printf("%d %c;", argv[i][j], argv[i][j]); putchar('\n'); } return 0;
}` and (on MacOS X 10.6.8, GCC 4.6.0) when invoked as `./xx $'a\0b'`, it gives two lines: `46 .;47 /;120 x;120 x;
` (the command name), and `97 a;0 ;77 M;65 A;`.  The `MA` is the start of the first environment variable.  There was only one argument, and it did not contain `\0`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler ,I mean it will be therre if you append another argument after `./xx $'a\0b'`

Comment: Output from `./xx $'a\0b' z z` is: (1) `46 .;47 /;120 x;120 x;` (2) `97 a;0 ;122 z;0 ;` (3) `122 z;0 ;122 z;0 ;` (4) `122 z;0 ;77 M;65 A;`, all on MacOS X 10.6.8.  You might get different results on a different platform - you should show them, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameters are passed into programs as C strings; in particular, the `execve()` syscall (lowest level visible to programs and generally ether very close to or identical to the kernel API) uses C strings, so it is not possible to pass `\0` within a parameter.  Note that, while the usual way the parameter vector is passed into the process's address space by the kernel is contiguous, so that an embedded `\0` would indeed split a parameter, the low level `exec()` interface uses a list of `(char *)`s, so an embedded `\0` would simply terminate the parameter early.

Comment: All of the strings seem by main are null-terminated anyway. There is no way of passing '\0' because there is no way of identifying that situation from the normal case.