# Print bytes into file using printf shell command

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to print the following data into file, but i get the following error: "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string".
Here is my program:

```
int main(void)
{
char* argv[] =  {"/bin/sh", "-c","printf '%b' '\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\x01\x00\x02\x03' > file.bin", NULL };
execve("/bin/sh", argv, NULL);

  return 1;
}
```

The problem is in the null byte in the middle of above text: `\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\x01\x00\x02\x03"`
Is there any way to do this like above ?

Comment: FYI you are returning an error by default (`return nonzero` usually indicates a problem).

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that the backslashes are interpreted in the C string, while you want to pass it as argument for the `sh` command.

Therefore you must double escape each backslash character.

```
int main(void)
{
    char* argv[] =  {"/bin/sh", "-c","printf '%b' '\\x7f\\x45\\x4c\\x46\\x01\\x00\\x02\\x03' > file.bin", NULL };
    execve("/bin/sh", argv, NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

There's a compiler extension that allows `R"(printf '%b' '\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\x01\x00\x02\x03' > file.bin)"` -- see [Does C support raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850244/does-c-support-raw-string-literals) , but for portability don't use it.

Also, it's not possible to pass raw null byte into `execve`, see those questions

- [What if there's '\0' character in command line input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560779/what-if-theres-0-character-in-command-line-input)
- [Can the null character to be passed to argv in the middle of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938639/can-the-null-character-to-be-passed-to-argv-in-the-middle-of-a-string)
- [execve args not copied beyond null byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007378/execve-args-not-copied-beyond-null-byte)